# change the metadata and copyright of jpg image with python3

Tags: python, image, metadata, exif, xmp

I want to change the metadata or exif or copyright of some images together.
I searched a lot and tried some libs like :

### exif : it had this error :
[the error of exif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQu3N.png)

### PIL : I didn't know how to use that.

### piexif : I had this error :
KeyError: 'Exif'

and some else that I can't remember the names but I couldn't use the because of errors.

============================================================================

anyone knows a way for me to change some metadata of a jpg?
I'm doing it with photoshop but it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Your question is very vague - please try and improve it. What metadata do you want to change exactly? What type/format of images? What Operating System? Do you have lots of images? Are they all in one directory? Where is the new metadata coming from? What did you try? Thank you.

Comment: I want to change Copyright - Author - Author Title - Description - Description  Writer - Keywords -Copyright  Notice  - Copyright  Info URL - Creator - creator's job Title - Address - Country - E-mail - website  =-=-=-=-= img format = JPG -=-==-=- on windows  =-=--=-= I have a lot of images -=-=-=-=- yes they are in a same directory -=-=-=- I have a file (xmp) for metadata to use , or I can write them =-=-=-= I need because  I spent a lot of time on this with Photoshop.

Comment: Should be a one-liner with `exiftool`. See https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4659.0

Comment: looks like that can help me but I dont know how to use this code== exiftool -tagsfromfile my_photo.xmp my_photo.jpg in VS Code

Comment: You just do it in your **Command Prompt** thing (?) on Windows.

Comment: Aha. but for me I should write it in my code. I don't know what should I do.